# How to horizontal list view without fixed height in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How can I solve the problem shown in the image below?
In the first case, the elements come to me with a certain height, then at another time the same elements come to me with a height less than the previous one, so an empty space remains at the bottom of the array!

How to avoid this case without using SingleChildScrollView or FittedBox?

[image]

The code:

```
SizedBox(
            height: 500,
            child: ListView.separated(
              itemCount: 5,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const SizedBox(width: 20),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(),
            ),
          ),
```

I tried many ways and it didn't work.

Comment: can you [edit] your code to include a complete example

Comment: You can try `Slivers` and `CustomScrollView` these widgets will give more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method: Set fixed height for your Container (wrap ListView), then allows your listview item resizeable, eg.

```
Container(
      height: 200,
  child: ListView.builder(
      ...
      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                         //imgame, avatar...
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                //some text
                ...
                maxLines: 2,
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replacing *ListView.builder* with *SingleChildScrollView+Row*

*Example: Select item and drag Slider to change it height, the parent container will fitted.*
[image]

*(open https://dartpad.dev/ and paster this code and press Run.)*

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class Data {
  final int id;
  double height;
  Data(this.id, this.height);
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var list = List<Data>.generate(100, (i) => Data(i + 1, 150));
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget renderList() {
    Widget renderItem(Data data) {
      return Card(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              selectedIndex = data.id;
            });
          },
          child: SizedBox(
            height: data.height,
            width: 100,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(data.id.toString()),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Card(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: list.map((i) => renderItem(i)).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget renderConfigPanel() {
    if (selectedIndex != 0) {
      return Card(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Slider(
              min: 100,
              max: 300,
              label: "Height",
              value: list[selectedIndex - 1].height,
              onChanged: (newHeight) {
                setState(() {
                  list[selectedIndex - 1] = Data(selectedIndex, newHeight);
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        renderList(),
        renderConfigPanel(),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```